# plots the function with arraysin matlab

Tags: matlab, function, plot

funcplot that plots the following function on interval [-pi,pi] using 1000
linearly spaced data points.How can I do that with arrays ? Idon't have any idea.

f(x) = 5cos (x4
/3)tan(e
0.2x
)cos(ln(4x))

Comment: [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first define an array for `x`

```
x = linspace(-pi, pi, 1000);
```

Then you need to compute`f` for the array `x`.

```
f = 5 * cos(x * 4 / 3) .* tan(exp(0.2 * x)) .* cos(log(4 * x));
```

Then plot `x` vs. `f` using `plot`.

```
%// Plot the real components
plot(x, real(f));

%// Plot the imaginary components
plot(x, imag(f));
```